# How to compile data from several workbooks in excel 2011

Tags: macos, excel, excel-2011, vba

I am trying to copy a line of data from several workbooks in a folder and paste them into a master workbook (in the same folder) using VBA for Excel 2011 Mac. I have the following code but continually run into a `Runtime error 1004`.

After debugging it highlights the `Workbooks.Open(MyFile)` line but I can't figure out why.  The path is correct.  Can anyone please advise on what is wrong?

I got the original code from http://www.familycomputerclub.com/transfer-data-from-multiple-workbooks-into-master-workbook-automatically-using-vba.html which is for Windows.  Any info would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
MyFile = ("/Users/administrator/Desktop/Excel")

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "Test.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    Range("A2:D2").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

    MyFile = Dir

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code ever even find your Test.xlsm workbook? The way it is written I don't think it possibly can...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MyFile = ("/Users/administrator/Desktop/Excel")` (why the parentheses by the way?), but that is not actually a valid path to a workbook, right?

I mean, surely it should point to a .xlsm file and not just to a directory... That should be what gives you the error.

I think you need to find all the workbooks in your directory first and then loop through those. The way your code is written now seems really wrong to me, but of course that doesn't mean it won't work. But I really think you need to parse the directory for .xlsm files first and then loop through those.

**UPDATE**

I think this code should now do what you want.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim directory As String
Dim file As Variant

directory = "C:\Users\RISE123\Desktop\NSRP\AFPR004\Foundations\20140702 - AFPR004 FA9 Change\"
file = Dir(directory)

Do While Len(file) > 0
    If InStr(1, file, ".xlsm", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        With Workbooks.Open(directory & file)
            Call .Worksheets(1).Range("A2:D2").Copy(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:D2"))
            Call .Close(False)
        End With
    End If
    file = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

But you will have to modify the starting directory path `directory`, as well as the logic in the `With` `End With` block to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. 
In regards to the path, I want to reference a folder which has several files in it.  That folder is named "Excel" and is on my Desktop.  However, the actual workbook file is Test.xlsm which I reference later.  Im confused as to how to reference a folder vs a file.  Can you clarify?

Many thanks

Comment: Well, right now you are referencing a path in `MyFile`. What you want is to loop through the files in your directory and open them one after the other. Take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba which shows how to loop through all files in a directory. You can then incorporate your logic for processing your workbook into that.

Comment: I went ahead and coded something up that should do what you need :)